# How to count clock cycles at -O3 using Code::Blocks 16.01 in Windows 10?

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

In my C program I am counting the number of clock cycles on a 64-bit Intel Corei5-2410M Sandy Bridge machine running Windows 10 Home but there is something strange. I compile the program both at -O2 and -O3 using Code::Blocks (CB) 16.01 in release build. For -O2 the clock cycles are okay but -O3 returns 0 cycles. For now, I'm not taking turbo-boost and hyper-threading into consideration but definitely will disable them later.

I use the following commands for compiling

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -O2 -m32 -IC:\GMP\include -c "E:\abc\main.c" -o obj\Release\main.o
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -O3 -m32 -IC:\GMP\include -c "E:\abc\main.c" -o obj\Release\main.o
```

We have

```
void schoolbook_9(int32_t *X, int32_t *Y, int64_t *Z){
Z[0] = (int64_t)X[0]*Y[0]  + (int64_t)X[1]*Y[1]  + (int64_t)X[2]*Y[2]  + (int64_t)X[3]*Y[3] + (int64_t)X[4]*Y[4] + (int64_t)X[5]*Y[5] + (int64_t)X[6]*Y[6] + (int64_t)X[7]*Y[7] + (int64_t)X[8]*Y[8];
Z[1] = (int64_t)X[9]*Y[0]  + (int64_t)X[0]*Y[1]  + (int64_t)X[1]*Y[2]  + (int64_t)X[2]*Y[3] + (int64_t)X[3]*Y[4] + (int64_t)X[4]*Y[5] + (int64_t)X[5]*Y[6] + (int64_t)X[6]*Y[7] + (int64_t)X[7]*Y[8];
Z[2] = (int64_t)X[10]*Y[0] + (int64_t)X[9]*Y[1]  + (int64_t)X[0]*Y[2]  + (int64_t)X[1]*Y[3] + (int64_t)X[2]*Y[4] + (int64_t)X[3]*Y[5] + (int64_t)X[4]*Y[6] + (int64_t)X[5]*Y[7] + (int64_t)X[6]*Y[8];
Z[3] = (int64_t)X[11]*Y[0] + (int64_t)X[10]*Y[1] + (int64_t)X[9]*Y[2]  + (int64_t)X[0]*Y[3] + (int64_t)X[1]*Y[4] + (int64_t)X[2]*Y[5] + (int64_t)X[3]*Y[6] + (int64_t)X[4]*Y[7] + (int64_t)X[5]*Y[8];
Z[4] = (int64_t)X[12]*Y[0] + (int64_t)X[11]*Y[1] + (int64_t)X[10]*Y[2] + (int64_t)X[9]*Y[3] + (int64_t)X[0]*Y[4] + (int64_t)X[1]*Y[5] + (int64_t)X[2]*Y[6] + (int64_t)X[3]*Y[7] + (int64_t)X[4]*Y[8];
Z[5] = (int64_t)X[13]*Y[0] + (int64_t)X[12]*Y[1] + (int64_t)X[11]*Y[2] + (int64_t)X[10]*Y[3] + (int64_t)X[9]*Y[4] + (int64_t)X[0]*Y[5] + (int64_t)X[1]*Y[6] + (int64_t)X[2]*Y[7] + (int64_t)X[3]*Y[8];
Z[6] = (int64_t)X[14]*Y[0] + (int64_t)X[13]*Y[1] + (int64_t)X[12]*Y[2] + (int64_t)X[11]*Y[3] + (int64_t)X[10]*Y[4] + (int64_t)X[9]*Y[5] + (int64_t)X[0]*Y[6] + (int64_t)X[1]*Y[7] + (int64_t)X[2]*Y[8];
Z[7] = (int64_t)X[15]*Y[0] + (int64_t)X[14]*Y[1] + (int64_t)X[13]*Y[2] + (int64_t)X[12]*Y[3] + (int64_t)X[11]*Y[4] + (int64_t)X[10]*Y[5] + (int64_t)X[9]*Y[6] + (int64_t)X[0]*Y[7] + (int64_t)X[1]*Y[8];
Z[8] = (int64_t)X[16]*Y[0] + (int64_t)X[15]*Y[1] + (int64_t)X[14]*Y[2] + (int64_t)X[13]*Y[3] + (int64_t)X[12]*Y[4] + (int64_t)X[11]*Y[5] + (int64_t)X[10]*Y[6] + (int64_t)X[9]*Y[7] + (int64_t)X[0]*Y[8];}
```

I'm counting the clock cycles as follows

```
int32_t X[17], Y[9];
int64_t Z[9];
utype64 start, end;
uint32_t i;

srand(time(NULL));
for(i=0; i<17; i++)
    X[i] = rand()%(uint32_t)pow(2.0, 29);
srand(time(NULL));
for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    Y[i] = rand()%(uint32_t)pow(2.0, 29);

start=rdtsc();
end=rdtscp();
start=rdtsc();
for(i=0; i<10000000; i++)
    schoolbook_9(X, Y, Z);

end=rdtscp();
printf("\n%s%"PRIu64"\n", "The cycles count using SB of size 9 is :: ", (end-start)/10000000);
```

I'm using the rdtscp instruction because my system supports it and may be it is not available on 32-bit machine therefore, I have tested my program both with/out rdtscp. The arguments X, Y, and Z are arrays where X and Y are 32-bit and Z is 64-bit.

So, my questions is how to get the cycles count at -O3? Because for the current code I get 0 cycle.

The flage *-ftree-loop-vectorize* is set at -O3 as described on this page https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html. Does it mean that loop has been vectorized? If yes, then how can one determine what is the length (4 elements, 6 elements etc.) of the vector?

Comment: Yes, I will update the question in few minutes. I'm calling rdtsc() and rdtscp() twice but actually it's recommended to call them thrice in the white paper of G. Paoloni at http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf

Comment: `pow(2.0, 29);` --> `1 << 29`

Answer (score 1):

It's because `end - start` is lower than `10000000` with `-O3`. Your division produce `0`.

```
utype64 result = end - start;
utype64 cycle = 10000000;
utype64 total = result / cycle;
utype64 rest = result % cycle;
printf("The cycles count using SB of size 9 is " PRIu64
       " and the rest is " PRIu64 "\n",
       total, rest);
```

And you should not call twice `srand(time(NULL));`. It is useless and can produce strange behavior.

Note: I can't test myself.

Comment: Yes, you are right that *(end-start)* < 10000000 and that's why I get 0 at -O3. This is the reason that I'm asking what to do for -O3? Don't you think that logically *end* is always greater than *start*? So, why utype64 result = *end* > *start* ? *end* - *start* : *start* - *end*; ?

Comment: @user110219 I don't remember why I do that... my bad. Whatever I don't understand your question anymore. You have the number of cycle because it's 0. I don't see the problem. maybe you can use [`clock_gettime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).

Comment: @user110219 There should not be difference between `-O[0|1|2|3]` just optimization so the behavior should not change. The only thing that change is that your program is faster.

Comment: -O3 is showing a strange behavior and I've also checked the values of *start* and *end* and the difference is something like 1600.

Comment: @user110219 What strange behavior do you have? wrong result? Maybe `-O3` do the optimization proposed by Lưu Vĩnh Phúc. `-O3` can be very aggressive. Your compiler probably detect that your function produce the same result every time and remove the loop. You should look what is the code generate by your compiler. https://gcc.godbolt.org/ for example.

Comment: By strange behavior I mean why the difference b/w *start* and *end* is around 1600 when the loop is executed for 10000000. Yes, -O3 is doing something very aggressive.

Comment: @user110219 Well this will be my last comment. This is not a strange behavior the purpose to `-O3` is to optimize the code. I look what is generate [here](https://godbolt.org/g/50F9Li), gcc and clang call `srand` and `rand` because don't call them change the behavior but like you see the call to `schoolbook_9` is gone because you don't do anything with `Z`. Your result `1600` is correct.